# What is the correct way to pronounce 'router'?

Tags: pronunciation

Merriam-Webster lists both *ˈrüt* and *ˈrau̇t* as possible pronunciations for *route* but only
*ˈrau̇-tər* for *router*.

Is it really wrong to pronounce *router* as *'rüter* ?

Comment: good question :).

Comment: So, Rowter for my US peeps. Rooter for UK peeps. Both are correct depending on where you live. It's just another Potato/Tomato difference between British and American English. If you think about it Rooter makes more sense as in to Route packets of data from one point to another. But whatever -_- each to their own.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are two different kinds of things called a "router", with two different pronunciations, originating from two different verbs "route" and "rout". The confusing part of this is that the two pronunciations overlap the two different things.

[image]

A **router** as above (computer thing, from verb "route"), or anything else which routes something, is "rooter" or "rowter" depending on how you pronounce "route" (US English has both "root" and "rowt", British English has only "root")

[image]

A **router** (woodworking tool, from verb "rout", an electrical one is shown above) is "rowter", never "rooter", in both the US and the UK and other countries. The dictionary entry may be referring to the wood tool only.

Source:
[Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/router?q=router) & 
[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/router)

Comment: I have never heard "router" pronounced differently for these two things. FWIW, I'm in the US.

Comment: @aphoria: Both "rowter"?

Comment: @aphoria - Over on the eastern edge of the pond what Shinto says would certainly be correct.

Comment: @Brian: how do you think it is incorrect now?

Comment: Good post, nice images.

Comment: @Shinto - which dictionary are you referring to in your answer?

Comment: I don't think there is anyone in the US who calls the electronic device a "rooter" rather than "rowter".

Comment: @Shinto - I don't think it is incorrect in any way, but I don't know what people call these things in America, so I wouldn't presume to have an opinion on the matter.

Comment: @JohnFx: I did not refer to any dictionary in preparing this answer.

Comment: Both sound like "shout".

Comment: I knew a guy in university, who spoke Canadian English (like me) and who called it a "rooter".  Drove me crazy.  He's the only one I've ever heard say that.

Comment: Probably should be pronounced rooter, but yeah rowter is alot nicer.

Comment: The computer network device is pronounced "rowter" in the US and "rooter" in the UK (speaking as a US network engineer who has had many discussions with UK colleagues)

Comment: Wait, British network admins actually say rooter‽ `:-o`

Comment: @Synetech - yep, the network device is a rooter because it puts packets on the correct route - as in route 66. The woodwork tool is a row-ter because it removes wood in the same chaotic manner as a 'rout' does in military parlance

Comment: @Martin, you do realize that a lot of people pronounce travel lines like *route 66* as *r-out* right? I don’t think I’ve ever heard of an airplane being *re-rooted*, only *re-r-outed*.

Comment: @Synetech - yes it was a slight dig, AE say r-out except for root66, probably because of the song

Comment: I believe there are some Americans who currently pronounce the noun *route* as "root" and the verb *route* as "rowt". This may have been influenced by the electronic device being called a "rowter." In my part of the country, airplanes often get "re-rowted," as @Synetech says, but highway names and travel plans are almost always "roots."

Comment: The Route 66 song also refers to the city of "Saint Louie", so it probably shouldn't be taken as a guide to accepted pronunciation of things :)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 A *rooter* is someone that digs up *roots*, and thus rhymes with *footer*.  It is not a common word.

Comment: @tchrist: _root_, like those things that keep the tree in the soil, and _foot_, those odd-shaped things at the end of your legs, have completely different vowels for me. So the "root" in "rooter" would rhyme with boot, scoot, loot, and flute.

Comment: Australian's, despite their UK heritage, are unfortunately increasingly using the American pronunciation despite pronouncing "route" the UK way.. :(

Comment: @tchrist - I don't know whether Mr.ShinyandNew安宇  considers himself to be a 'foreigner'. However as a native British English speaker from birth and throughout my life, I rhyme those words in exactly the same way he does. Am I a foreigner?

Comment: "The Internet for Dummies" (2nd ed), written by USA authors and published by IDG, a USA publisher, in 1994 on actual paper *(I know, I know)* states i.a.: `... this kind of router is usually pronounced "ROOter,"because a "ROWter" is something you use in a woodworking shop (except in Australia.)` Yeah, a LOT of the contents of that book is now obsolete....

Answer (score 21):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* (NOAD) reports that *router* has two different meanings.

> router 1 /ˈraʊdər/
>   noun
>   A power tool with a shaped cutter, used in carpentry for making grooves for joints, decorative moldings, etc.

> router 2 /ˈraʊdər/
>   noun
>   A device that forwards data packets to the appropriate parts of a computer network.

In both the cases, the pronunciation is the same.

As comparison, the pronunciation of *route* (as reported from the NOAD) is /rut/, /raʊt/; the pronunciation of *rout* is /raʊt/.

In British English, the word is pronounced /ˈraʊtə/ when it has the first meaning, and /ˈruːtə/ in the second case.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: Your answer says the opposite of what I am saying, as you say that the word is pronounced differently basing on the meaning; I reported that in American English that is not true.

Comment: Despite the votes so far I agree with kiamlauluno. This is what I have experienced in common usage and he backs it up with a solid citation. However, personally I have always felt that the networking device should be called a 'root-er' because it routes data. Plus that song route-66 has me all screwed up.

Comment: kiamlaluno, you're using the IPA version of the NOAD (are you on a Mac by any chance?). The diacritical version, which is also the one found in the NOAD WordWeb add-on, says:


"router 1 |ˈroutər|
noun
a power tool with a shaped cutter, used in carpentry for making grooves for joints, decorative moldings, etc.
router 2 |ˈroōtər; ˈroutər|
noun
a device that forwards data packets to the appropriate parts of a computer network."


I have never, however, heard any American call a router(2) "rooter" instead of "rowter."

Comment: I use the Mac OS X Dictionary; the pronunciation I reported is the pronunciation shown when I select _American IPA_ in the preferences of the application; when I select _British IPA_, I obtain a different pronunciation (the British one).

Comment: Do you have the "US English (Diacritical)" option?

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary has ˈruːtə (computing) and raʊtə (power tool). There is a definite locale issue here.

Comment: The pronunciation I report is the one I get when I select _American English (IPA)_; as far as I know, the pronunciation |ˈraʊdər| is American English, as it is the pronunciation |ˈɪdəli| for _Italy_ (notice how the _t_ is pronounced for both the words and compare it with |əˈtæljən|, the pronunciation of _Italian_). When I report the pronunciation reported by the NOAD, I am always reporting the pronunciation of a word in American English (as I didn't select _British English (IPA) as pronunciation).

Comment: I know but there is another option called US English (Diacritical) which doesn't use IPA but some other custom symbols (like Merriam Webster)

Answer (score 10):

Where I live both things are called "rowter" even though we say "root" 66, so if they lived in the U.S. That would be standard.  If they said "rooter" it might sound like a thing used to clean drains.

Answer (score 5):

A router (rooter) routes. A router (rauter) routs.

To my ear, the American pronunciation is really grating.

Comment: Sorry, eh.   However, be aware that not all USAmericans use "rowter" -- some do use "rooter".  I was recently in a Cisco networking class where the instructor, a longtime Las Vegas resident originally from Maryland, said "rooter."   Much to the consternation of the predominately Southern US group.

Comment: +1 for noting the root (!) of the word. It should be added that most Americans pronounce "route" to rhyme with "rout", so their pronunciation is consistent. British usage, despite being what I use, is no more "correct" than American.

Answer (score 5):

I was born in the US. I pronounce the computer apparatus "rooter" as in "hooter". I just had a manager at work try to correct me today, but I stuck to my guns.

Answer (score 3):

A rooter is used to clean pipes (specifically to remove roots, or other obstructions).

Because that pronunciation exists, router is pronounced as indicated in the other answers.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the origin of the word for fixing pipes.  Even though it's almost totally unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary (CALD) does not include the word 'router'

However, the meaning of route has been described as the following:

> route UK /rut/ US /rut/ , UK /raʊt/  noun   [ C  ]
>
> 1. a particular way or direction between places 
>      The route we had planned took us right across Greece.
>      I live  on  a bus route so I can easily get to work.
> 2. a method of achieving something 
>      A college education is often the best route  to  a good job.
> 3. US       ( UK      round ) a set of regular visits that you make to a number of places or people, especially in order to take products as part of your job
>
> route  UK /rut/ US /rut/ , UK /raʊt/  verb   [ T   usually + adv/prep  ]
>   to send 
>       Deliveries are routed via/by way of London.

Since the CALD did not specify from which sound the word 'router' is originated, so my conclusion is 'router' can be pronounced as 'ruter' or 'rauter' according to UK pronunciation! However, if the company which produced the device pronounces it as a 'rauter' then it is 'rauter' otherwise it is 'ruter'.